# convert this code to accept Unicode text

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have a script written in PHP but there is a problem

this code does not accept Unicode text. when I pass Unicode text to this code, it returns some invalid characters.

```
public static function compile(&$subject, $replace, $with) {
        $placeholders = array_combine($replace, $with);

        $condition  = '{[a-z0-9\_\- ]+:[a-z_]+}';
        $inner      = '((?:(?!{/?if).)*)';
        $pattern    = '#{if ('.$condition.')}'.$inner.'{/if}#is';

        while (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match)) {
            $placeholder = $match[1];
            $content     = $match[2];

            // if empty value remove whole line
            // else show line but remove pseudo-code
            $subject = preg_replace($pattern,
                                    empty($placeholders[$placeholder]) ? '' : addcslashes($content, '$'),
                                    $subject,
                                    1);
        }
    }
```

please help me.

Comment: Can you please show some sample input, along with what you expected to get and what you actually got?

Comment: I passed **سلام** and the output is something like **طءع‌ط**

Comment: I am not familiar with those characters, but I am vaguely aware that the same letter can be drawn in different ways depending on if it's at the start or end of a word? Is this the case with your text at all, or are they completely garbled and meaningless characters?

Comment: they completely garbled and meaningless characters

Comment: There is a "u" flag that `preg_replace` needs to properly handle UTF-8. The pattern then is something like `'/[a-z]*/u'`. You should be able to find more info on the web.

Comment: Two more notes: You should read PSR-2 concerning the formatting of PHP code, it makes it easier for others to read and understand. Further, why do you repeatedly assign to `$subject`? Instead of taking a reference, you should return the result, which is again something that makes code easier to understand.

Comment: What is the character encoding of the input?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, for unicode you need to use multibyte string methods:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php